# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system

Tags: 16.04, filesystem, python3, read-only

the following error showed up while I was training a neural network:

```
    File "train.py", line 397, in <module>
    File "train.py", line 270, in train
    File "train.py", line 335, in train_one_epochs
    File "train.py", line 113, in log_string
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 57, in apport_excepthook
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 896, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1139, in find_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1113, in _get_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1225, in find_spec
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1264, in _fill_cache
OSError: [Error 5] Input/output error: '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "train.py", line 397, in <module>
    File "train.py", line 270, in train
    File "train.py", line 335, in train_one_epoch
    File "train.py", line 113, in log_string
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system
```

The code where error happened is:

```
111    def log_string(out_str):
112        LOG_FOUT.write(out_str+'\n')
113        LOG_FOUT.flush()
114        print(out_str)
```

Does anyone know the reason? Any help or suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: in which folder did you try to write it?

Comment: @Yaron in folder **~/shuo/OURpointNet2/scannet/log**, and this folder is created using `os.mkdir`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `df -h ~/shuo/OURpointNet2/scannet/log` and `cat /proc/mount`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the filesystem the application is logging to was mounted as read only.

You can try remounting it with

```
mount -o remount,rw {mount point}
```

Where {mount point} is the directory where the FS is mounted.

Comment: Thank you @Doom8890. This error happens during training, which means at first the filesystem the application was logging to was read-and-write, but after a few epochs this error happened. Does this mean that the permission of one folder or file could change during running a python file?

Comment: Are multiple users using your system? Maybe somebody remounted it. Otherwise my only guess is some kind of system error caused it to remount as read only.